# How to just pop up a wait message window in rebol view?

Tags: rebol

I just want to popup a wait message window in rebol view, but there's no option to do so with View command as

```
View win: layout [text "wait"]

do-some-lengthy-task

Unview win
```

will block the script until the user close the message himself which is not wanted here of course.

So how to make non-blocking view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
View/new win: layout [button "Do-It" [print "ok"]]
repeat i 10 [print i wait 0:0:1] ;lengthy-task
Unview win
```

Answer (score 1):

fl: flash "Hang about .... "

do stuff...

unview/only fl